# Sphere minus interval is upper half plane $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} - [a \ , b] \simeq \mathcal{H}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $a<b$.  How can I show that  $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} - [a \ , b]$ is biholomorphic to upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$? Any hints or reference are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about the Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: @FlorianR Thank you very much! Should I delete this question?

Comment: I am rather new myself, I am not sure. If you want to, you can answer your question yourself and accept it then. Edit: I can also quickly write down a full answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a Mobius transformation, $\Bbb C_\infty-[a,b]$ is equivalent
to $U$ which is $\Bbb C$ with the nonpositive real axis removed. Then
$z\mapsto i\sqrt z$ (principal branch) maps $U$ to the upper half-plane.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{C}_{\infty} - [a \ , b]$ is simply connected and not all of $\mathbb{C}$, by Riemann mapping theorem, it is biholomorphic to $\mathcal{H}$